# localhost prefix Angular 2 development

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular project where I am currently trying to access an online api. The problem is that when I use Angular 2 token and set the apiBase to the url, it gets prefixed with http://localhost:4200. The apiBase doesn't work with any prefix. Is there any way to drop the prefix so it can be a basic url?
An example of what I get is:

```
http://localhost:4200/google.com
```

when I need it to be just

```
google.com
```

And this is the variable i'm working with.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  token_auth_config: {
    apiBase: 'google.com'
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post your service code?

Comment: *when I use Angular 2 token*: what does that mean? Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `apiBase` is defined as a relative url. Change url to include protocol like `http://google.com` and it will work. However you will probably encounter CORS restrictions. But that's another topic.

You could also use [Proxy to Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) if your API listens really on relative url.